# htaccess redirect to ssl only for certain pages and www non secure for the other pages

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, ssl

I need to redirect all requests to the site to www and only certain pages to https without www, since for some reason the ssl certificate bought by our customer doesn't cover www.
After looking around I managed to accomplish most of it. But what happens is once we have visited a secure url page, the other pages will stay on https.
Here is what I have so far in the.htaccess:

```
#Redirect to www
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^./]+\.[^./]+$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^./]+)\.[^./]+\.[^./]+$ [NC]
RewriteCond %1 !=www [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]


# Force SSL on checkout login account and admin pages
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} checkout|login|my-account|administrator|webshop
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L
```

I miss the part that will redirect to www non secure if https is on and not belonging to the listed urls. But I'm not familiar at all with regex and rewrite rules.
Some help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Try using this code instead :

```
# Force SSL on checkout login account and admin pages
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} checkout|login|my-account|administrator|webshop
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%2/$1 [R=301,L,QSA]

# Remove SSL on other pages
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !checkout|login|my-account|administrator|webshop
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%2/$1 [R=301,L,QSA]

# Force www for non https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. But the SSL directives cause the secure urls just land on the homepage.
Maybe, that's caused by the Joomla own rewrite rules conflicting with these rules ?

Comment: yes it can conflict,also make sure that these rules are the first in your htaccess.