# How to force one page to http (when https is forced site wide)

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

Hello I am running a WP install and annoyingly on one page that doesn't really need https I have to request http images from another site (that I don't own) and the image(s) update every 1hr so I can't just copy and paste them, I've looked into copy/saving them, proxies etc..

I'll need one page to have http only regardless for those two options to work anyway so I might as well just force the page I need to have http, so my question is.. if you guys are still following me! ha.. is with the `.htaccess` below how can I add an exception for the home/index of my site to make `https://mysite.co.nz` to `http://mysite.co.nz`  (and `https://www` etc..)

```
# Test Force ssl

RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://mysite.co.nz/$1 [R,L]
```

Any help would be beyond amazing

Comment: What is the problem? .. Is it going cross on protocols? .. I overcome links by omitting the protocol by "//to.website.com/.... " .. So no http/htps. Hope that may help...

Comment: That doesn't work since it forces https, the image won't display..

Comment: the real question is why is the image not displaying.. It seems you are solving a problem that should be non-existent. When serving images from https it does not matter what protocol the remote site uses, unless your certificate is invalid or incorrectly installed.

Comment: the image is on another site http://theimage.com/image.png (the site has no https) my site is https you can NOT display non-secure content on a site that has https

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these 2 rules:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} =443
RewriteRule ^/?$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} =80 
RewriteRule . https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this - [htaccess redirect to ssl only for certain pages and www non secure for the other pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12260816/htaccess-redirect-to-ssl-only-for-certain-pages-and-www-non-secure-for-the-other)

```
# Remove SSL on other pages
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !checkout|login|my-account|administrator|webshop
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%2/$1 [R=301,L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thanks but causes a redirection loop